# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < and no error 404

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get an error when I load the app on the browser. I don't know what I'm doing wrong and all myfiles are found, no error 404. The error is

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
ExtensibleNavBarDirective:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
angular.min.js:17 Uncaught Error: No module: DashboardAppUIModule
```

Error happens at this line of my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

My Directive.js is

```
define(['angular','ui/module'],function(angular){
angular.module('DashboardAppUIModule').directive("extNavBar", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",        // directive is an Element (not Attribute)
        templateUrl: "ExtensibleNavBarTemplate.html",
        replace: true,        // replace original markup with template
        transclude: false    // do not copy original HTML content});
    }
 });
})
```

My html on the same directory

```
<nav class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <ul class="nav nav-list">
        <li><a href="#/home"> <i class="icon-home"></i></a></li>

    </ul>
    <ul class='nav nav-list' ng-repeat='module in modules'>
        <li ><a href='#/{{module.moduleNamespace}}/main'>{{module.moduleLabel}}</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!--<ul class="nav nav-list" ng-repeat="module in modules" >
        <li ><a href="#/{{module.moduleNamespace}}/main">{{module.moduleLabel}}</a></li>

    </ul>-->

    <form class="navbar-search pull-right">
        <input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search">
    </form>
</div>
```

My module.js

```
define(['angular'],function(angular){
return angular.module('DashboardAppUIModule',['ui.bootstrap']);
});
```

and finally my modules.json

```
  {
"moduleName": "DashboardAppUIModule",
"moduleLabel": "ui",
"moduleNamespace": "ui",
"moduleStates": [
  {
    "stateName": "ui",
    "abstract": true,
    "url": "/ui",
    "templateUrl": "/app/extensionModules/ui/views/main.html"
  },
  {
    "stateName": "ui.main",
    "abstract": false,
    "url": "/main",
    "templateUrl": "/app/extensionModules/ui/views/ui.main.html"
  },
  {
    "stateName": "ui.title",
    "abstract": false,
    "url": "/title",
    "templateUrl": "/app/extensionModules/ui/views/ui.title.html"
  }
],
"moduleDependencies": null,
"moduleExports": [
  "/module",
  "/ExtensibleNavBarDirective"
],
"scriptDependencies": null
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an error on my paths on modules.json, correcting the path to my module and directive resolved the issues

```
  "ui/module",
  "ui/directives/ExtensibleNavBarDirective"
```